# Trying to resize a table in the middle of a sheet.

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to resize a table located in the middle of my sheet. Code snippet - most integers you're seeing are actually variables, but there's no sense in having a huge amount of extra code.

```
Sub StackOverFlowTest()
    destSheet = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Test")
    Set DestTb = destSheet.ListObjects("CTROutputTable")
    DestTb.Resize DestTb.Range.Resize(100+1,5)
End Sub
```

I have a table, DestTb, of N rows and 5 columns. I'd like it to turn into 100 rows + a header column. It's located at an unknown (Read: Dynamic) location in my sheet. Moving data into it directly isn't auto-expanding the table, so I need to resize the table first.

How can I easily resize the number of rows in a table?

Full code so far, if you're really interested:

https://gist.github.com/OlivierHJ/5b039a8c5da05d137f5c8d00f6108309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an updated answer because OP has a dynamic table. That means the table won't be always in same range, so we need to get the address of ListObject everytime.

For this code, I needed two extra functions to locate the where is the table every time. 1 UDF to extract the text part of an address and 1 UDF to extract the number part of Address.

```
Sub RESIZZE_TABLE()
Dim DestTb As ListObject
Set DestTb = Sheets("Hoja1").ListObjects("Tabla1")
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim MyFirstCell As String
Dim MyLastCol As String
Dim MyLastRow As String

Dim ColCount As Integer
    ColCount = 5 'number of columns in your table
    MyFirstCell = Range(DestTb).Cells(0, 1).Address
    TotalRows = (DestTb.DataBodyRange.Count / ColCount) 'how many rows got table
    MyLastCol = TextOnly(Range(DestTb).Cells(TotalRows, ColCount).Address) 'we get letter of last column of table
    MyLastRow = onlyDigits(Range(DestTb).Cells(TotalRows, ColCount).Address) 'we get number of last row of table

    DestTb.Resize Range(MyFirstCell & ":" & MyLastCol & (MyLastRow + 2)) 'change 2 by number of rows you want to increase
End Sub

Private Function TextOnly(ByVal xValue As String) As String
'source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1625-excel-extract-text-from-alphanumeric-string.html
'adapted for SO
Dim OutValue As String
Dim xIndex As Byte

For xIndex = 1 To Len(xValue)
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
        OutValue = OutValue & Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
    End If
Next
TextOnly = OutValue
End Function

Private Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function
```

Tested with a table moving around a worksheet. It did not matter where it was the table, the code always resized the table with no problems.

Hope this works now!

Comment: The issue with that code is my table is in an unknown (read: Dynamic) location. I can't assume the location of anything.

Comment: LastTableRow contains the last row of your table. You just need how to get the first row. Let me work on that and update my answer

Comment: So, it looks like it should work. For some reason, my .Address keeps giving me output in the form A1:A1, instead of A1. Trying to figure out how/why now...

Comment: It appears to have been a bonafide computer error. After awhile it started generating cells again.

Comment: So a few final notes: I ended up modifying the code a bit. Your solution answered the question "I need to add X rows to my table", while I needed the answer "I need my table to be X rows". I accomplished this by essentially setting totalrows to 0, and subtracting 1 near the end.

Comment: Good to know that my code helped a bit. If you want, post your full code as answer so future users can read it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if you are reducing the number of rows you will wish to clear the cells that no longer belong to the table.

```
Dim iTBLrws As Long, rng As Range, rngOLDBDY As Range

iTBLrws  = 100

With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Test").ListObjects("CTROutputTable")
    Set rngOLDBDY = .DataBodyRange
    .Resize .Range.Cells(1, 1).Resize(iTBLrws, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count)
    If rngOLDBDY.Rows.Count > .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count Then
        For Each rng In rngOLDBDY
            If Intersect(rng, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                rng.Clear
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I'm increasing the number of rows, no issues there. I'm only decreasing with removing duplicates, and that part of the code is working fantastically.

Comment: Well, I'll leave my response here in case some future viewer of this thread finds it helpful.