# Updating the inventory with a click button

Tags: excel, vba, macos, button, updates

I have been trying to adjust the VBA code for a while now but without any success.

I would like to choose the cells (like the Range function) instead of looking through the whole row/columns. The tables will be surrounded by text and images, that's why you see the words "test" around the tables.

```
Sub Inventory_change()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Cl In .Range("A3:A9").SpecialCells(6).Offset(1).RangeSpecialCells(6)
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Total").Columns("C").Find(Cl.Value).Offset(, 6) = Columns("C").Find(Cl.Value).Offset(, 6) - Cl.Offset(, 1)
    Next Cl
End With
```

From A3:A9 are the products that have been sold and F3:F9 is the amount sold.

[image: Receipt]

From C6:C12 are the products in the inventory and H6:H12 is the amount left in stock.

[image: Inventory]

Thanks!

Comment: So you only want to select things?

Comment: Looking at the tables of your Image, looks like you want `ListObjects` You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel). Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958276/trying-to-resize-a-table-in-the-middle-of-a-sheet/48958415#48958415). Maybe it can help you a little bit on how to deal with ListObjects through VBA

Comment: @Luuklag the VBA code searches in columns, but because there is text surrounding the tables it gives an "error" with Range you can call specific cells so it doesn't call the surround texts in the columns.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will give them a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're after this:

```
Dim cl As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Total").Columns("C") 'reference "Total" sheet columns C range
    For Each cl In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through "Sheet1" sheet range "A3:A9" cells with "constant" content 
        .Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 5) = .Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 5) - cl.Offset(, 5) ' update cells 5 columns to the right of referenced one (i.e.  "Total" sheet columns H)
    Next cl
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! it seems to work, just need to see if it works for the rest of my sheets. also thanks for the explanations